# Azure Search how to choose query boosting values

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search

I am implementing search on a website and have 3 types of document; `products`, `articles` and `content`. `products` may be active (discontinued=0) or discontinued (discontinued=1). `articles` and `content` are always indexed as discontinued=0, though this info is ignored for those document types.

I want to apply boosting to my query to get the following ranking (order) but without applying an ordering clause:

1. active products
2. discontinued products
3. articles
4. general content

Ignoring `articles` and `content`, I get the correct ordering when I boost discontinued `products` by 1 and active products by 1000 (I cannot use negative boost values as my underlying search system is Azure search).

I tried to boost my "contentType" field by 100000 for `products`, 50000 for `articles` and 10000 for `content`, but this breaks the ordering of active/discontinued products (although the split between, products, articles and content is otherwise correct).

How do I go about calculating/choosing the correct boost values for this scenario?